# How to get the variable names from the string for the format() method

Tags: python

Lets say I have this line:

```
"My name is {name}".format(name="qwerty")
```

I know that the variable name is `name` and so I can fill it.
But what if the word inside the `{}` always changes, like this:

```
"My name is {name}"
"My name is {n}"
"My name is {myname}"
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
"My name is {*}".format(*=get_value(*))
```

Where `*` is what ever word was given inside the `{}`

Hope I was clear.

---

**EDIT:**

```
def get_value(var):
    return mydict.get(var)

def printme(str):
    print str.format(var1=get_value(var1), var2=get_value(var2))

printme("my name is {name} {lastname}")
printme("your {gender} is a {sex}")
```

Having this, I can't hard code any of the variables inside `printme` function.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can parse the format yourself with the [`string.Formatter()` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter) to list all references:

```
from string import Formatter

names = [fn for _, fn, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fn is not None]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> yourstring = "My name is {myname}"
>>> [fn for _, fn, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fn is not None]
['myname']
```

You could subclass `Formatter` to do something more fancy; the [`Formatter.get_field()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.get_field) method is called for each parsed field name, for example, so a subclass could work harder to find the right object to use.

Comment: But now, how do i use `names` in the `format` method to get all the values?

Comment: @MichaelR: How were you planning to pair up the names with values? You can always use `dict(zip(names, values))` to create a dictionary, provided you know many values you need to provide.

Comment: @MichaelR: `yourstring.format(**dict(zip(names, values)))`.

Comment: I wanted to use this: `yourstring.format([(i,get_value(i)) for i in names])`
but it gives me an error for some reason :-\

Comment: `get_value()` is a method defined on the `Formatter` class; I was talking about a more complex setup where you subclass that class to have `get_value()` do something different in your overridden method. Read the `Formatter` documentation for more details.

Comment: I ment my `get_value` method ive written

Comment: Right; you'd still have to build a dictionary; `yourstring.format(**{i: get_value(i) for i in names})` if you are on Python 2.7 or newer.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.8 added an awesome solution for this using f-strings:

```py
my_var = 123
print(f"{my_var = }")
```

Which will print

```
my_var = 123
```

Comment: what's happening here? is this a special syntax within f-strings? `my_var = ` doesn't evaluate to a valid python expression, so it must be that string formatting is treating this construction differently. I had no idea this was possible!

Comment: looks documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable instead of `name="querty"`

```
name1="This is my name";

>>"My name is {name}".format(name=name1)
```

Output:

```
'My name is abc'
```

Another example ,

```
a=["A","B","C","D","E"]
>>> for i in a:
...     print "My name is {name}".format(name=i)
```

Output:

```
My name is A
My name is B
My name is C
My name is D
My name is E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_arg(yourstring):
    arg_list = []
    pin = False
    for ch in yourstring:
        if ch == "{":
            pin = True
        elif ch == "}":
            pin = False
            arg_list.append(text)
            text = ""
        elif pin:
            text +=ch
    return arg_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Or an alternative is to use a function:

```
def format_string(name):
    return "My name is {name}".format(name="qwerty")
```

Then call it:

```
format_string("whatever")
```

Answer (score -1):

If your data is in a dictionary (according to your edited question) then you can use the dictionary as a parameter for format.

```
data = {'first_name': 'Monty',
        'last_name': 'Python'}

print('Hello {first_name}'.format(**data))
print('Hello {last_name}'.format(**data))
```