# How to set and access variables with formatted name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables, string-formatting

Let's say I have a lot of variables like so **`myvar_{number}`** e.g. `myvar_1`, `myvar_2`, `myvar_3`, ...`myvar_1000`.

Skeleton code:

Full piece of code:

```
# supposing that instead of 1000 global variables there are only two of them:
myvar_1=None
# do some other stuff with myvar_1
#[...]
myvar_8=None
# do some other stuff with myvar_8
#[...]

my_new_lst = [1, 8] # supposed list with 1000 variables but for the sake of example just two of them

# Here I want to set each variable to its index number multiplied by 2, e.g. myvar_1 = 2 * 1 = 2; myvar_8 = 2 * 8 = 16; and finally print them.

# so, I tried this:
for each in my_new_lst:
    print(f'{global myvar_{each}=2*each}') # I know it just print it but how to set it?

# finally print them:
print(myvar_1)
print(myvar_8)
```

The error it gives to me is:

```
 File "<fstring>", line 1
    (avg_interval_{each}=2*each)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

P.S. I've found [How to get the variable names from the string for the format() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830226/how-to-get-the-variable-names-from-the-string-for-the-format-method) which is asking about something somehow similar but it doesn't help.

Comment: For all that is holy, *use a list!*

Comment: @deceze  Could you give to me an example, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `myvars = [None, None, None, ...]`